# Using Markov's inequality to find upper bound of tail probability for Gaussian random variable(Q-function).

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

[image]Suppose $X$ be the standard normal distriution. Its tail probability will be

$$Q(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{t}^{\infty}e^{-\frac {x^2}2}\,{\rm d}x$$

I need to find the upper bound of $Q$ function using Markov's inequality.
It's easy to get the answer when $t>0$, but I have trouble working with $t<0$.

And I can't understand the hint.

Comment: What do you mean by the upper bound of Q? It should be 1. What are you looking for? Please be more clear

Comment: It's one of the problem in my homework which states that Q function represents the tail probability of a Gaussain random variable, and we can use Markov's inequality to produce an upper bounds on the Q-function.

Comment: Since 1 is actually the upper bounds, but that's not tight enough. I want a more precise bound by using the Markov's inequality.

Comment: The Markov Inequality is only valid of non-negative random variables. Hence you cannot directly apply it to Gaussian random variable. So how can you appropriately modify the random variable so that you can use the Markov inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF of $|X|$ is
$$
g(t)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} e^{-t^2/2}, t\geq 0.
$$

By integration, $E(|X|)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}.$

$|X|$ is a positive distribution. Using Markov, 
$$
Q(t)=P(X\geq t)=\frac{1}{2}P(|X|\geq t)\\
\leq \frac{1}{2}\frac{E(|X|)}{t}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}}{2t}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }\space t}
$$
for $t>0$ only. Of course, this upper bond is meaningless for $t<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }\space t}$, because we have $Q(t)< 1$ before anything.

For $t\leq 0$, the upper bond is $1$. You can find the lower bond by symmetry.

Comment: I get it.  Maybe I am making it too complicated.